# heroku deploy failed using nodejs

Tags: node.js, express, heroku, npm, ionic-framework

I am trying to push local files to heroku and getting below error.
I have my code in [github](https://github.com/asimkh/apps/tree/haz/)

Can someone help me in this. Thanks

```
$ heroku buildpacks:set heroku/nodejs
Buildpack set. Next release on haz will use heroku/nodejs.
Run git push heroku master to create a new release using this buildpack.
$ git push heroku master
Counting objects: 693, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (500/500), done.
Writing objects: 100% (693/693), 63.10 MiB | 2.54 MiB/s, done.
Total 693 (delta 220), reused 639 (delta 171)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote: 
remote: -----> Using set buildpack heroku/nodejs
remote: 
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to detect set buildpack heroku/nodejs
remote: More info: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks#detection-failure
remote: 
remote: Verifying deploy....
remote: 
remote: !   Push rejected to haz.
remote: 
To https://git.heroku.com/haz.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/haz.git'
$
```

for package.json

```
{
  "name": "haz",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Hazzir: An Ionic project",
  "private": "true",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.13.3"    
  },
  "main": "serve.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node serve.js",
    "postinstall": "bower install && grunt build",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "engines": {
      "node": "4.1.2",
      "npm": "3.4.0"
    },

  "keywords": [
    "Haz",
    "product"
  ],
  "author": "Asim Khan",
  "license": "ISC",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/asimkh/apps/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/asimkh/apps#readme"
}
```

I tested locally, app is runnning at port 5000 using express

```
var express = require('express'),
    app = express();

app.use(express.static('www'));

// CORS (Cross-Origin Resource Sharing) headers to support Cross-site HTTP requests
app.all('*', function(req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With");
    next();
});

// API Routes
// app.get('/blah', routeHandler);

app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 5000);

app.listen(app.get('port'), function () {
    console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
});
```

Answer (score 4):

I see a few issues here

1) You need a procfile - https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-nodejs#define-a-procfile

2)
You don't specify the engines in your package.json

```
"engines": {
  "node": "0.10.x"
},
```

See here- https://discussion.heroku.com/t/the-official-node-js-buildpack-is-going-on-a-diet/100

3) You have comitted your `node_modules` directory to git. You should be able to download packages using `npm install` (that's what your `packages.json` file is for)

Delete this directory, and commit the delete to git.
Then, create a `.gitignore` file. Add the following line to your `.gitignore` file:

```
node_modules
```

commit this .gitignore file to your repository.

Git will now ignore your `node_modules_` directory

Comment: I've added more detail

Comment: I update github resp, check https://github.com/asimkh/apps/tree/haz/ , i add procfile, engine update and also gitignore

Comment: your node_modules dir is still in the repository. you need to delete it

Comment: i removed the directory locally and online, got Error stiill ====> To https://git.heroku.com/haz.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/haz.git'

Comment: try using `git push -f` when you push to heroku

Comment: I have using a branch so i tried  git push heroku yourbranch:master, nows its work successfully, thanks so much - check this uploaded link === > http://haz.herokuapp.com/#/

Comment: done, thanks again. i will glad giving you tech or design support in future.

Comment: I'm having the same problem, but the above steps do not work. One key difference in my situation: I had files in node_modules and I'm on Windows. I'm still getting "Filename too long" errors during the push even though I have deleted the node_modules folder and added node_modules to .gitignore.

Comment: @JayBienvenu this looks like it should be a separate question. Filename too long is a different error

Comment: My error is "Push rejected, failed to detect set buildpack heroku/nodejs." The file path issues is a symptom that may or may not be related. Everything else about my problem is the same.

Answer (score 2):

Try: git add -f package.json
It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

git init and then readding heroku remote worked

```
heroku git:remote -a yourappname
```